# SQL Server 2012 (T-SQL) Select day to month group by

Tags: sql-server, date, aggregate-functions

Good day,

I am aggregating daily data to monthly data.

```
TABLE daily_data:
item_from,
item_to,
agg_day,
average_day_rate,
min_day_rate,
max_day_rate,
closing_day_rate

TABLE monthly_data:
item_from,
item_to,
agg_month,
average_month_rate,
min_month_rate,
max_month_rate,
closing_month_rate
```

select data:

```
DECLARE @rundate       DATE;
DECLARE @yesterday     DATE;
DECLARE @firstofmonth  DATE;

SET @runday        = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
SET @yesterday     = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()))
SET @firstofmonth  = DATEADD(dd, 1, EOMONTH(@yesterday, -1))

SELECT
  item_from,
  item_to,
  DATEADD(dd, 1, EOMONTH(agg_day, -1))                                     agg_month,
  SUM(average_day_rate)/COUNT(DISTINCT(agg_day))                          average_month_rate,
  MIN(min_day_rate)                                                       min_month_rate,
  MAX(max_day_rate)                                                       max_month_rate,
  (SELECT closing_day_rate FROM daily_data WHERE agg_day = MAX(agg_day))  closing_month_rate
FROM
  daily_data
WHERE
  agg_day >= @firstofmonth
  and agg_day < @runday
GROUP BY
  item_from,
  item_to,
  DATEADD(dd, 1, EOMONTH(agg_day, -1))
```

Result: 
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

I have tried just using agg-day in the group by, changing the where to a having, but without any success.
In PL-SQL I would be using

```
SELECT
  item_from,
  item_to,
  trunc(agg_day, MONTH)                                                  agg_month,
  SUM(average_day_rate)/COUNT(DISTINCT(agg_day))                          average_month_rate,
  MIN(min_day_rate)                                                       min_month_rate,
  MAX(max_day_rate)                                                       max_month_rate,
  (SELECT closing_day_rate FROM daily_data WHERE agg_day = MAX(agg_day))  closing_month_rate
FROM
  daily_data
WHERE
  agg_day >= @firstofmonth
  and agg_day < @runday
GROUP BY
  item_from,
  item_to,
  trunc(agg_day, MONTH)
```

Please Help.

Comment: Why don't you put SELECT closing_day_rate FROM daily_data WHERE agg_day = MAX(agg_day) into a cte - or even better: the result directly into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
DECLARE @rundate        DATE;
DECLARE @yesterday      DATE;
DECLARE @firstofmonth   DATE;
DECLARE @lastdayclosing SMALLMONEY;

SET @runday        = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
SET @yesterday     = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()))
SET @firstofmonth  = DATEADD(dd, 1, EOMONTH(@yesterday, -1))
SET @lastdayclosing = (SELECT close_rate FROM exchange_rate_daily WHERE exr_date = @yesterday)

SELECT
  item_from,
  item_to,
  @firstofmonth                                   agg_month,
  SUM(average_day_rate)/COUNT(DISTINCT(agg_day))  average_month_rate,
  MIN(min_day_rate)                               min_month_rate,
  MAX(max_day_rate)                               max_month_rate,
  @lstdayclosing                                  closing_month_rate
FROM
  daily_data
WHERE
  agg_day >= @firstofmonth
  and agg_day < @runday
GROUP BY
  item_from,
  item_to
;
```